# Querying a date column with Laravel's query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When writing a query against a table with a date column using the Laravel query builder, what data type should be used? The following **should** return 13 results but instead returns nothing:

```
$date = new \DateTime("-2 days");
Model::whereDate($date)->get();
```

Dumping the query shows that laravel is trying this:

```
array(3) {
  'query' =>
  string(62) "select * from `table` where `date` = ?"
  'bindings' =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class DateTime#310 (3) {
      public $date =>
      string(19) "2013-10-07 14:39:11"
      public $timezone_type =>
      int(3)
      public $timezone =>
      string(3) "UTC"
    }
  }
  'time' =>
  double(5.55)
}
```

Writing the query as `Model::whereDate($date->format("Y-m-d"))->get()` instead works but doesn't seem like the Laravel way to do it.

Is there a specific object type I should be passing into the query to filter by a date column?

**EDIT**: The model in this example looks like this:

```
class Model extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'table';

    public function getDates() {
        return array('date');
    }
}
```

The table it refers to looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table(
  some_field VARCHAR(255),
  date DATE
) ENGINE = 'InnoDB';
```

Laravel thinks the date column is a string: `Model::lists('date')` returns an array of strings, as does `DB::table('table')->lists('date')`.

Changing `$date = new \DateTime("-2 days");` to `$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2)` doesn't allow me to query the `date` column directly with the Carbon object.

**UPDATED:** For whatever reason, the built-in MySQL `date` to `\Carbon\Carbon` isn't working for me, so the simplest solution was to write one as a query scope:

```
public function scopeDate($query, \Carbon\Carbon $date) {
    return $query->whereDate($date->toDateString());
}
```

Comment: i am confuse here a little. it sayd query builder in title but you tagged with eloquent. so which approach you are using?

Comment: @itachi: Using an Eloquent model based on the table and doing a direct query, i.e., `DB::table('table')` both exhibit the behavior I mention in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add your column in the getDates() array. By doing this Eloquent will automatically convert your datetime to Carbon object.

From the docs:

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at, updated_at, and
>   deleted_at columns to instances of Carbon, which provides an
>   assortment of helpful methods, and extends the native PHP DateTime
>   class.

See this:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators

Again, providing the date in the right format (Y-m-d) may still be necessary because it is not always possible to tell how to interpret a given date

Comment: It seems like providing the right format is my only option, but I don't see why there would be any issues interpreting a column with the MySQL `date` type. Neither Eloquent nor the query builder seem able to compare the `date` type against either a `\DateTime` or a `\Carbon\Carbon`.

Answer (score 1):

As told here, Laravel uses Carbon as a DateTime class, you can perform it using:

```
Model::whereDate( \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2) )->get();
```

Comment: That still doesn't work, but `Model::whereDate(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateString())->get();` does.

Comment: It worked for me here when I posted. Could you, please, test it using QueryBuilder? >> `DB::table('table')->whereDate( $date )->get();` Might be a bug on Eloquent.

Comment: It's the same in QueryBuilder. I should mention that the site is using PHP 5.3.3 (the latest version available in CentOS's package repository), so it's most likely a compatibility issue.

Comment: Where is located that `whereDate` method in the sources?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo the `whereDate` is dynamically scoped. You can do this in Laravel: `whereCOLUMN($value)` which is basically a shorthand of `where('COLUMN', '=', $value)`

Comment: @GladToHelp, thanks! I think I had brain lapse... I knew about that dynamic method... somehow I though it was something _special_.

Comment: If PHP 5.3.3 didn't supported this, you should get errors, not an odd behaviour. This is a long shot: it could be your database server not supporting it. Is this MySQL? I'm using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I am wondering if this would work if you changed the SQL DATE type with DATETIME in your table definition.

Comment: Afaik, a change to date time would require to set a range to filter.

Comment: It is MySQL, and a [pull request from 5 months ago](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1325) indicates that this should work. But `var_dump`ing a query result object indicates that MySQL dates are being converted to strings, not `Carbon` objects. The attribute getter in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Database\Model looks like it should be casting what's in the `getDates()` array to the proper objects, but for whatever reason, it's not happening.

Comment: What happens if you change the date like this: `$date = new DateTime; $date->modify('-2 days');` and then pass it to the `whereDate()` method? Does it make any difference?

Comment: @GladToHelp - that still returns nothing. Based on what you and AntonioCarlosRibeiro have said, this must be some weird fluke in my setup.